# Give an unbiased estimators for the third central moment of the underlying distribution.

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, parameter-estimation

Let $X_{i}, i=1,\ldots, n$ denote a random simple of size $n$ from a population with mean $3$. Assume that $\hat{\theta}_{2}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]$ and that $\hat{\theta}_{3}$ is an unbiased estimator for $\mathbb{E}[X^3]$. Give an unbiased estimator for the third central moment of the underlying distribution.

**My approach:**

I know that $$\mu_{3}=\mathbb{E}[(X-3)^{3}]=\mathbb{E}[X^{3}]-9\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]+54$$
so, we can see that $\hat{\mu_{3}}=\hat{\theta}_{3}-9\hat{\theta}_{2}+54$ is an unbiased estimator for
$\mu_{3}$ of the underlying distribution.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is unbiased and so correct.  To check:

$$\mathbb E[\hat{\mu_{3}}]\\=\mathbb E[\hat{\theta}_{3}]-9\mathbb E[\hat{\theta}_{2}]+54  \\ = \mathbb E[X^3]-3\cdot3\cdot\mathbb E[X^2]+3 \cdot3^2\cdot\mathbb E[X] - 3^3 \\ = \mathbb E[(X-3)^3]$$

It is not the only unbiased estimator.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification.